# Add/Remove class "current" to li in nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a navigation bar in which I want to add a class to the li tag of the current page so that I can add css to show what page you are on. I have attempted it using this script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
        $("#nav.ul.li").click(function() {
        $("#nav.ul.li").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the html I am using for my navbar:

```
    <nav id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="Events Calendar.html">Events Calender</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Rules and Regulations.html">Rules</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Facilities.html">Facilities</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="Video Guides.html">Video Guides</a></li>
            <li><a href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="Store.html">Store</a></li>
            <li><a href="FindUs.html">Where to find us</a></li>
            <li><a href="Contact Us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="About Us.html">About Us</a></li>

        </ul>
    </nav>
```

However this script didn't work, so using javascript/jquery what is the best way to set a class on click to the li tags in my navigation bar?

All help much appreciated!

Comment: `.` is a class selector, you don't have any classes within the posted code.

Comment: When the page navigates the class is not going to be there when the new page loads...

Comment: ^ agreed, unless youre using a templatie system and your jquery is static code on all the pages or you're making a spa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the dots used like in `#nav.ul.li` and put space between them:

```
$(function() {
$("#nav ul li").click(function() {//or #nav > ul > li for direct element
   $("#nav ul li").removeClass("current");
   $(this).addClass("current");
});
});
```

Use `.` when you have a class on them  like `$('.sel')` for `<div class="sel">` and use `#` for element which has id as you normally use in css.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("#nav > ul > li")` instead of `$("#nav.ul.li")`. jQuery selector uses the same syntax as CSS. Other solution like `$("#nav ul li")` will also add/remove classes in `unordered list` puttes inside one of your `<li>` elements.